# See exact publish date of an npm package

Tags: npm

With npm, when I use the `npm view [package]` command, I can see the publish date relative to today, for example:

```
$ npm view lodash

lodash@4.17.21 | MIT | deps: none | versions: 114
[...]    
published over a year ago by bnjmnt4n <benjamin@dev.ofcr.se>
```

How can I get the exact publish date-time in a format such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**tl;dr** - Utilize the solution provided in the *"Solution"* section below.

---

Using [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) you can run the following command:

```
$ npm view express time --json
```

This logs something like the following to the console:

> ```json
> {
>   "modified": "2018-10-31T23:01:06.660Z",
>   "created": "2010-12-29T19:38:25.450Z",
>   "0.14.0": "2010-12-29T19:38:25.450Z",
>   "0.14.1": "2010-12-29T19:38:25.450Z",
>   ...
>   "4.16.3": "2018-03-12T17:50:14.119Z",
>   "4.16.4": "2018-10-11T03:59:14.308Z",
>   "5.0.0-alpha.7": "2018-10-27T03:12:11.060Z"
> }
> ```

As you can see, the command *(above)* returns a JSON object containing properties; `modified`, `created`, and also has properties for each version (e.g. `"0.14.0"`, `"0.14.1"`, etc... ). The associated value for each property is a date.

---

#### How to obtain the published date for a specific version?

The docs for `npm-view` state the following;

> You can view child fields by separating them with a period.

Therefore, obtaining the values (i.e. dates) for `modified` and `created` you can run either of the following commands respectively:

```bash
$ npm view express time.modified

# prints --> `2018-10-31T23:01:06.660Z`
```

and

```bash
$ npm view express time.created

# prints --> `2010-12-29T19:38:25.450Z`
```

However, when obtaining the value/date for a specific version property/key such as `4.16.4` you'll need to use a different approach, because commands such as the following *do not work*:

```bash
# This does not work...
$ npm view express time.4.16.4
```

```bash
# This also does not work...
$ npm view express time.'4.16.4'
```

```bash
# This does not work either...
$ npm view express time["4.16.4"]
```

**Solution:**

The following command demonstrates how to successfully obtain the published date for version `4.16.4` of the [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) package:

```bash
$ npm view express time --json | node -e "process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {console.log(JSON.parse(data)['4.16.4'])});"

# prints: --> 2018-10-11T03:59:14.308Z
```

*Note: You'll need to replace the `'4.16.4'` part with the appropriate version as required*.

This solution:

1. Runs the `npm view express time --json` command and pipes the JSON to a nodejs script.
2. The nodejs script utilizes the builtin [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) to read the piped JSON from `stdin` *(fd 0)*.
3. We then utilize [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the JSON string, and obtain the value of the property/key named `4.16.4`

**Note**

If you want the published date for the latest version you could run the following two bash commands:

```bash
$ version=$(npm view express version)
$ npm view express time --json | node -e "process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {console.log(JSON.parse(data)['"$version"'])});"

# prints: --> 2018-10-11T03:59:14.308Z
```

Here we firstly run `npm view express version` (to obtain the latest version number) and assign the value returned to the variable named `version` (i.e. we utilize [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)). Then we reference the `version` value in the node script.

You can also chain the two commands using the `&&` operator to form a one line command as follows:

```bash
$ version=$(npm view express version) && npm view express time --json | node -e "process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {console.log(JSON.parse(data)['"$version"'])});"

# prints: --> 2018-10-11T03:59:14.308Z
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, thanks! My good enough solution was `npm view express time --json | grep 4.16.4` that outputs `  "4.16.4": "2018-10-11T03:59:14.308Z",`

Comment: @vicentedealencar - You're welcome. That way is not a cross-platform solution, and yes using `grep` can yield something on _*nix_ platforms. However, your example `grep` pattern doesn't guarantee the correct result for  various reasons, such as; **1)** If  version `14.16.4` is released in the future  you'll return that too. **2)** The pattern `4.16.4` may exist in the actual time. For instance; running: `npm view express time --json | grep 9.14.3` also returns the same result... Consider safeguarding against these unwanted issues by changing your `grep` pattern to  `... | grep "\"4.16.4\""`

Answer (score 0):

On npm **8**+ (Node 16), use `time[<version number>]`:

```bash
npm view lodash time[4.17.21]
```

For the latest version:

```bash
npm view lodash time[$(npm view lodash version)]
```

Comment: When I run this command with a version number in the brackets, I receive an error: `no matches found: time`. But if I exclude the brackets and just run `npm view package-name time`, then it shows me a list of the specific dates for all previous versions of the package which gives me the information I need.