# Determining release date of a (web) software

Tags: release, release-management, semantic-versioning, software-release

Is there any technique to determine the release date of a software. I don't want to use crawler or something similiar, because I have more than 300 softwares in my dataset. For example I want to determine the release date of Modernizr 3.1.4.

Comment: If a software/package has been published to the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) registry then it's possible to determine its _"published date"_ for a specific version. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148989/see-exact-publish-date-of-an-npm-package/53153005#53153005) describes how. However,  [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr) version `3.1.4` was never published to npm. There are several other Modernizr versions that have been published, e.g. `3.1.0'` and `3.2.0`. The published date/time for version `3.2.0` was `2015-10-29T18:33:25.655Z` for example.

Comment: i decided to use repositories to retrieve such data, there is really no public data

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal way to determine when a piece of software was released.

The closest you could get is to "Scour the contents of the distribution, website and, if applicable, VCS and hope that it is documented somewhere"

Comment: i thought maybe there is a dataset or something similiar