# Check the last update date of bootstrap and syncfusion in my Angular project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, command-line-interface, syncfusion

I am struggling to know the date of the day when the bootstrap and syncfusion libraries were updated in my Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

We want to inform you that you can check the installed version of your Syncfusion NPM packages. Then, you can find the date of that particular package in NPM registry from the below link.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base

Also, you can find check our release notes for the exact date of the release for the particular version.

Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/release-notes/18.1.59/?type=all

Please get back to us if you need any further assistance on this.

Comment: I actually wanted to know the date when a particular syncfusion version was installed in my Angular project. Is there any command to know this?

Comment: You can use “npm view {package-name} time” command to get the published date of the latest package. You can also refer the below npm documentation and stackoverflow discussion for further details.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148989/see-exact-publish-date-of-an-npm-package