# How to create a .env with with the apikey of openai in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, api-key, openai-api, .env

I have a page in a react.js app calling the api of openai and it works locally when I have the actual apikey  in the page but I have been trying to create the .env and I have not figure it out.
This is what I have

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Form, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const {Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require ('openai');
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apikey: process.env.REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY
          });
const openai= new OpenAIApi(configuration)
.....
```

If I have the actual apikey instead of 'process.env.REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY' it works.
I created a .env file with
REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY= 'the actual key'
no luck,

Any suggestions,
thank you,
Marlon

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .env file is in your root directory. Also, you must restart the server after you create or change the .env.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you write in your env file with no space and quote"" like this:

```
REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY=youropenaiapikeyhere
```

and restart your app.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion dotenv is not a preferred method of managing environment in [production applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604414/why-i-should-not-use-dotenv-in-production-mode), you might consider having a session stored in a user secure session (maybe with redis) depending on your backend.

If you're not concerned about the key being secure, an alternative to .env is leveraging the /public directory of the react app. The following is a pattern I have used

Given the following directory structure

```bash
project-root
  /public/config.json
  /src/App.js
  /src/index.js
  /src/providers/context/config.js
```

```js
// /src/providers/context/config.js
import { createContext, Context } from "react";

const context = createContext({
  config: undefined
});

export { context as configContext };

export default function ConfigProvider(props) {
  const {
    children,
    config
  } = props;

  return (
    <context.Provider value={{ config }}>
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  )
}
```

```js
// index.js

import ConfigContext from './providers/ConfigContext';
// You can use fetch or any other http client.
import axios from 'axios';
import App from './App';

async function configure() {
  try {
    // You could store this in localStorage or indexeddb depending on your implantation
    const { data: config } = await axios('./config.json');

    root.render(<React.StrictMode>
      <ConfigContext config={config} >
        <App />
      </ConfigContext>
    </React.StrictMode>);
  } catch (error) {
    // handle your errors here
  }
}

configure();
```

This provider pattern will allow you to pass configuration down to any child components, not limited to the key you're using.