# npm: Tool to check flag packages that are not properly maintained / check against criteria

Tags: node.js, npm

I am looking for some tool or npm package that we can use to verify our used npm packages against certain critiera, e.g. that is was updated in the last 6 months or whether it has a certain license (e.g. MIT).
Especially the check regarding the last update date seems to be not that popular as I couldnt find anything regarding that.

In the best case, something that we can integrate with GitHub Actions so that we can automate that check.

Thanks a lot!

Greetings,
Philip

---

I already looked for tools / ways how we can get that data, e.g. npm show or https://packagequality.com/. However, all of them would require us to do some scripting ourselves, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find any tool that could be used for that, but I found a way how I can fetch the relevant data from the NPM Registry.

Requesting the following endpoint (e.g. for axios): https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/

This will return a key called *time* that contains the release dates of all the releases. You can then just select the latest version of it and get its date.

Answer (score 0):

Consider run dependencies checker tool that npm built-in

https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

It might not satisfy your needs in certain areas

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly (as far as I can see) this does not fulfill my main concern: Checking when the date of the last release of a dependency.

Comment: Then, Check the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148989/see-exact-publish-date-of-an-npm-package